ER- диаграмма. Отношения в ISA hierarchy, что такое partial, total, exclusive и overlapping? В чем их отличие?
Возникла проблема с пониманием в ER диаграмме - ISA иерархии. Там есть 4 вида отношений partial, total, exclusive и overlapping. Не могу понять, как они связывают и в чем их отличие. Если можно, то жизненный пример, будет лучшим объяснением.

Занимался базами 100  лет назад (еще на первой работе) и с тех пор всегда думал, что отношения в ER  это one-to-one, one-to-many и т.д. Прямо заинтересовали... Полез в гугл и узнал, что в ER на связи можно накладывать ограничения (Participation  constrains). Именно к ним относятся термины partial, total и т.д.  Далее, гугл  в помощь ... (я спрашивал, в частности "What is participation in an ER diagram?")

Спасибо большое, нам просто в университете так и сказали relationship, может быть перевод неправильный.
